# Mysql NOT EXISTS with two separate tables does not seem to work as desired

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I am trying to process data for each `case_type` for each `state`, `city` and `court_complex`, in order to achieve this i have created a table called `case_pointer` that saves the combination of each of the above. In addition to `case_pointer` that shows processed cases there i have also created a table called `skippers` that has a state_id, city_id, court_complex and case_type id. skippers need to exclude state, city or court_complex from the final pointer table.

Here is my query so far, but it is working as opposite. it shows records that exists in skippers instead of excluding them.

```
SELECT cp.id    AS case_pointerID, 
       ct.id    AS caseTypeID, 
       ct.ct_id AS casetypeCode, 
       ct.cc_id AS cc_id, 
       ct.name  AS caseTypeName, 
       co.wid   AS complexCode, 
       co.id    AS complex_id, 
       co.name  AS courtName, 
       ci.id    AS city_id, 
       ci.wid   AS cityCode, 
       ci.name  AS cityName, 
       st.id    AS state_id, 
       st.name  AS stateName, 
       st.wid   AS stateCode 
FROM   case_types ct 
       LEFT JOIN court_complex co 
              ON ct.cc_id = co.id 
       LEFT JOIN city ci 
              ON co.city_id = ci.id 
       LEFT JOIN state st 
              ON ci.state_id = st.id 
       LEFT JOIN case_pointer cp 
              ON ct.id = cp.casetypeid 
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
        (SELECT 1 
        FROM case_pointer cp 
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT null 
                      FROM skippers sk 
                      WHERE sk.state_id = cp.state_id)
         ) 
       OR cp.id IS NULL 
       ORDER BY st.id ASC, ct.id ASC, co.id ASC
       LIMIT 5
```

Please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you're doing correct `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` operator?

Comment: yes, i have tested subqueries separately and they are working as expected. i have also tested it in a static table and they work. is it because i am using a JOIN?

Comment: Please include table schema and data example into your question. If you can make a fiddle here https://www.db-fiddle.com/ or here http://sqlfiddle.com/ , it will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NOT EXISTS` subquery does not seem make any connection to the main query (alias ‘cp’ used twice), hence the ineffectiveness.

Also, looks like some errors on parentheses.